# Can't get my python code to find jpg file even though it is located in the correct folder

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Okay, so I cannot understand why this does not work. Every time I run the code it searches for a different picture but it never finds it. When I go to the specified location and search for the image I find it immediately. But i somehow still get the same error message.[enter image description here]

```py
id='../content/drive/MyDrive/dog-breed-identification/train/000bec180eb18c7604dcecc8fe0dba07.jpg'
dogs = pd.read_csv('../content/drive/MyDrive/dog-breed-identification/labels.csv')
dogs = dogs.sample(20)
dogs['file'] = dogs.id.map(lambda id: f'../content/drive/MyDrive/dog-breed-identification/train/{id}.jpg')
dogs['image'] = dogs.file.map(lambda f: get_thumbnail(f))
dogs.head()
```

I am trying to get this code to work:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/samayshikhar/dog-breed-identification-2-0

Does anyone know what the issue can be?
(I run the code in google colab)

I have tried changing {id} to a specific name, and that works. The problem is that the model will ot be able to predict dog breeds.

Error code (highlighted in image)[screenshot] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neHKO.png)

Comment: Your main issue is that you posted your code in an image file. Can you repost it in text?

Comment: You set id to a file path but here `dogs['file'] = dogs.id.map(lambda id: f'../content/drive/MyDrive/dog-breed-identification/train/{id}.jpg')
` you are basically inserting the whole file path in that string before the '.jpg'.

Comment: Are you sure you have mounted the drive correctly and image files can actually be shown? Try to use any image library to display image in that folder to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to get it work:

1. Mount drive and create symbolic link to specific folder you will be using, which is dog-breed-identification in your case

```bash
#mount drive
%cd ..
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

# this creates a symbolic link so that now the path /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/ is equal to /mydrive
!ln -s /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/ /mydrive

# list the contents of /mydrive
!ls /mydrive

#Navigate to /mydrive/dog-breed-identification
%cd /mydrive/dog-breed-identification
```

2. Use your code

```py
id='/mydrive/dog-breed-identification/train/000bec180eb18c7604dcecc8fe0dba07.jpg'
dogs = pd.read_csv('/mydrive/dog-breed-identification/labels.csv')
dogs = dogs.sample(20)
dogs['file'] = dogs.id.map(lambda id: f'/mydrive/dog-breed-identification/train/{id}.jpg')
dogs['image'] = dogs.file.map(lambda f: get_thumbnail(f))
dogs.head()
```